# How can i get the id of the hidden field and pass it to my query?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my script. I want to get the `id` of the hidden field in my page and pass it to fetch.php

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
    var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({  
        url: "fetch.php",  
        method: "post",  
        data: { employee_id: employee_id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {  
            $('#name').val(data.lname);
            $('#overtime').val(data.OT); 
            $('#OT_date').val(data.outw); 
            $('#employee_id').val(data.id); 
            $('#overtimeModal').modal('show');
        }  
    });   
}); // end of edit data function
```

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo  '<tr>
            <td><center>'.$row['lname'].'</td>
            <td><center>'.$row['outs'].'</td>
            <td><center>'.$row['outw'].'</td>
            <td><center>'.$row['OT'].' HR/HRS</td>
            <td><center><input type="hidden" name="OT_date" id="'.$row['OW'].'" /></td>
            <td><center><input type="button" name="btnedit" value="APPROVE" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="searchbutton btn-primary view_data"></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="button" name="btnapprove" value="editortest" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="searchbutton btn-primary edit_data"></center></td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Here is the `OTDATE` hidden field and I want to get the id of it. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Is that click is working or not? Are you alert or console the employee_id?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `value` attribute of `input` ?

Comment: thanks for the help masters !! the button is working i tried it.. but the problem is the variables that I'm passing to my fetch.php .. i have a query there to fetch results where employee_id equal to the passed employee id from the jscript.. but if i only use employee id the query will give me wrong results .. so i need to get the date also and use it in my query..

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you can traverse the DOM from the clicked `.edit_data` button and find the nearest `:hidden` element within the same `tr`. You can then store a reference to that element itself. This negates the need to even know the `id` of the field:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
    var employee_id = this.id;
    var $otdate = $(this).closest('tr').find(':hidden');

    $.ajax({  
        url: "fetch.php",  
        method: "post",  
        data: { employee_id: employee_id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {  
            $('#name').val(data.lname);
            $('#overtime').val(data.OT); 
            $otdate.val(data.outw); // use the element here
            $('#employee_id').val(data.id); 
            $('#overtimeModal').modal('show');
        }  
    });   
});
```

Note that you can use any selector you like to get the hidden input, I just used `:hidden` in this example for simplicity.

Comment: thank you sir for the response .. how can i check if i get the right $otdate ? 
its not showing when i put it in the success:function()

Comment: You can check the `$otdate.length` to see if the element is found (it should return `1`)

Comment: Also, have you checked that the AJAX function is completing successfuly?

Comment: it returns 1 sir.. but how can i check if the date that i get is correct ? i'm new to stackoverflow.. :) how can i comment images ?

Comment: Ah - do you mean how can you check if the value of the input is valid? If so, I would suggest you start a new question for that

Comment: thanks for always replying sir.. but i would like to check the date that is fetch by $otdate..

Comment: What do you mean by 'check'?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking. I understand that you want to check the value, but you've not stated against what, or where the value to check is. I would suggest you start a new question about it making it completely clear what you're trying to achieve and what data you have.

Comment: okay sir.. ill start a new one.. :) thanks a lot sir for helping me. i'm new to this .. and my english is not that good.. haha but ill try my best to express myself.. thanks again sir

Comment: No problem, glad to help - as least as best I could :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch it like this as you have only one hidden input specified.

```
var hiddenId =  $("input[type='hidden']").attr('id');
```

Otherwise you could fetch hidden input field by "specific" name,

```
var hiddenId =  $("input[name='input_field_name']").attr('id');
```

In your case the name of the hidden input is "OT_date" so you should find it like this, we don't know what will be the "id" given to id as it is retrieved from =>  id="'.$row["id"].'" , hence following solution should suffice.

```
var hiddenId =  $("input[name='OT_date']").attr('id');
```

Traverse each row and find in that row  the hidden element.

```
 $('tr').each(function() {
    var hiddenId =  $(this).find("input[name='OT_date']").attr('id');
 });
```

Comment: thank you sir for the help.. should i use the name attrib ? and put $row[''] ? to it ?

Comment: @arima I have updated my answer for more clarification. Please Upvote if solves your concern.

Comment: @arima then you need to loop on all <tr> and search for id for each hidden element within that <tr>. I have updated for this issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer again.. but i'm very new in using ajax.. where should i put the code ? I've tried to put it after var employee_id.. but its not working.. thanks

Comment: @arima you should not add more questions in one question. We provide you answer on your actual question. please update what your actually require and what you are trying to send to server.

Comment: okay sir.. thanks a lot sir.. ill make another one.. :) i'm sorry for this.. ill try to express myself more accurate on my next question..im not good in english thats why haha :) but i really appreciate the help.. thank sir

Comment: @arima please upvote for your actual concern in this question :)

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )
```

for your problem

```
   var hiddenId = $("input[name='OT_date']").attr('id');
```

Comment: thanks sir.. how can i check the value that is being returned by this script ?

Comment: you can check it in console using `console.log(hiddenId)` and it will return you array of ids

Comment: first check your code by source code. how many elements are printed

Comment: what do you mean sir by the elements ?

Answer (score 0):

First check in console that click event works or not!!

And then try this:

For without hidden field:

```
  var employee_id = $('.edit_data').attr("id");
```

For hidden field:

```
  var employee_id = $("input[name=OT_date]").attr("id");
```

Comment: thanks sir.. the button is working its already giving me results... but the results given by my query is wrong .. thats why i need to get the OT date here and pass it to the query in fetch,php